# Display Superscript in SSRS reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, string-formatting, reporting-services, superscript

I m working on SSRS 2008.
i want to display date as 1<sup>st</sup> January 2011..
but "st" should be in superscipt ..
not like "1st".

is there any way to display "st", "nd","rd" and "th" in superscipt without installing any custom font type(other Font Type).

Answer (score 42):

just copy and paste from the following list:

ABC⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ 
ABC₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉ ₊ ₋ ₌ ₍ ₎

ABCᵃ ᵇ ᶜ ᵈ ᵉ ᶠ ᵍ ʰ ⁱ ʲ ᵏ ˡ ᵐ ⁿ ᵒ ᵖ ʳ ˢ ᵗ ᵘ ᵛ ʷ ˣ ʸ ᶻ

ABCᴬ ᴮ ᴰ ᴱ ᴳ ᴴ ᴵ ᴶ ᴷ ᴸ ᴹ ᴺ ᴼ ᴾ ᴿ ᵀ ᵁ ᵂ

ABCₐ ₑ ᵢ ₒ ᵣ ᵤ ᵥ ₓ

ABC½ ¼ ¾ ⅓ ⅔ ⅕ ⅖ ⅗ ⅘ ⅙ ⅚ ⅛ ⅜ ⅝ ⅞ № ℠ ™ © ®

ABC^ ± ¶

Comment: is there a reason for no superscript for capitalized C,F,S...?

Comment: how did you format them? i can't seem to mimic it, I need to put [1][1] and [x][x] into the same super scripted text.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe...

You are limited to what can be done with [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). Font size and spacing also refer to the whole text box. So it isn't "native"

However, [superscript is unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_superscript) so you may be able to to do it with some fancy expression that concatenate characters. I'd suggest custom code.

I haven't tried this, but these articles mention it

- http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jason/archive/2010/12/06/subscripts-and-superscripts-in-ssrs-reports.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/SSRSSuperscript.aspx

Comment: In 2008, you can set the placeholder format to HTML and use certain HTML tags in your formatting (e.g. `="Some <b>bold</b> text"` works); I don't know if that includes `<sup>`, or maybe a `<span>` you could style, though, as I'm only on 2005.

Comment: Guyz .. it works for 0-9 only ... i need "st" , "th", "nd" ..
i know that superscripts....
i need to know about words that i mentioned ..
i dont need 0-9 or n as superscript ..

Comment: @Touseef: then no, you can't do this

Answer (score 1):

I am not looking for credit here as above solution has answered it for you but for beginners sake, I use a code function within my report.

So in my SQL say I have Number field, then I add a new field OrdinalNumber:

```
SELECT ..., Number, 
       CASE WHEN (Number % 100) BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN 4
            WHEN (Number % 10) = 1 THEN 1
            WHEN (Number % 10) = 2 THEN 2
            WHEN (Number % 10) = 3 THEN 3
            ELSE 4 END AS OrdinalNumber,
...
```

Then my code function:

```
Function OrdinalText(ByVal OrdinalNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim result As String
    Select Case OrdinalNumber
        Case 1
            result = "ˢᵗ"
        Case 2
            result = "ⁿᵈ"
        Case 3
            result = "ʳᵈ"
        Case Else
            result = "ᵗʰ"
    End Select
Return result
```

End Function

Then in the report textbox I use the expression:

```
=CStr(Fields!Number.Value) & Code.OrdinalText(Fields!OrdinalNumber.Value)
```